# How to Concatenate a digit number within a column without truncating?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

Using SQL Server Management Studio.

So I have a problem. I need to update the information of the cell phone numbers of the Column that I have. For Now, I have this table:

```
Patients | City_PhoneCode | CellPhone_Number
---------+----------------+-----------------
Mark A.              86           8688903442
Ally B.              55           5577564553
```

Notice that the City_PhoneCode is actually joined together with rest of the string in Cell_PhoneNumber. I need to put the number '9' after the PhoneCode in CellPone_Number Column, which would be in the 3rd spot. I tried to concatenate the digit in the third position but I get the error "String or binary data would be truncated."

I tried this query:

```
Update Patient
Set CellPhone_Number = Concat(City_PhoneCode, '9', CellPhone_Number)
```

But it was unsuccessful;

I tried to remove the first two digits, but the end result is always the same. I looked for it and I found it was due to the datatype not being able to hold the values I was trying to give because the values might be too big for the datatype.

I can't really alter the datatype as only the DB_Admin have this permission in this moment...

is there a way to fix this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of removing the first TWO digits, you should remove the first THREE, and concatenate with `City_PhoneCode + '9'`

But for a really elegant solution, you should look at SQL Server's [STUFF function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/stuff-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017).  You can use it to basically tell SQL Server "Replace the third character in the string with a '9'"

Answer (score 0):

Seems your column can hold 10 characters at most, so this is not possible without modifying the table definition because even after removing the first two digits, you are going to add three more which makes it 11 characters.
One workaround may be to strip 2 characters from the start of CellPhone_Number  and replace that with 9 and in any query you can use concat(City_PhoneCode,CellPhone_Number). The final table will look like this.

```
Patients | City_PhoneCode | CellPhone_Number
---------+----------------+-----------------
Mark A.              86           988903442
Ally B.              55           977564553
```

and in subsequent query you can use `concat(City_PhoneCode,CellPhone_Number)` instead of `CellPhone_Number`.